# How can I do JSON serializer ignore navigation properties?

Tags: json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I am exactly in the same case that this question:
[How do I make JSON.NET ignore object relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292010/how-do-i-make-json-net-ignore-object-relationships)

I see the proposed solution and I know I must use a Contract Revolver, and I also see the code of the Contract Resolver, but I do not know how to use it.

- Should I use it in the WebApiConfig.vb?
- Should I modify my Entity Model anyway?

Comment: If you are in the same situation than me, here is my advice: forget it and change you controller to OData. It works perfectly, and there is not problem with JSON serializer.

Comment: Carlos, my bellow solution works, may you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: I have marked your answer, RAM, because it has some upvotes, so it must work. But I comment this because it can be useful (if was for me). In the constructor, Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled did the trick:         public ExampleController()
        {
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

Comment: Thank you. Also my answer works in both `True` & `False` values of `LazyLoadingEnabled` property.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It is a useful question and I hope this help:

### A)

If you have created your models manually (without `Entity Framework`), **mark the relation properties as `virtual` first.**

If your models were created by `EF`, It has already done it for you and each `Relation Property` is marked as `virtual`, as seen below:

[image]

**`Sample class:`**

```
public class PC
{
    public int FileFolderId {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<string> Libs { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<string> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<string> Files { get; set; }
}
```

### B)

Those relation properties can now be ignored by the `JSON` serializer by using the following `ContractResolver` for `JSON.NET`:

**`CustomResolver:`**

```
class CustomResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly List<string> _namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep=new List<string>(new String[]{});

    public CustomResolver(){}

    public CustomResolver(IEnumerable<string> namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep)
    {
        this._namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep = namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep.Select(x=>x.ToLower()).ToList();
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var propInfo = member as PropertyInfo;
        if (propInfo != null)
        {
            if (propInfo.GetMethod.IsVirtual && !propInfo.GetMethod.IsFinal
                && !_namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep.Contains(propInfo.Name.ToLower()))
            {
                prop.ShouldSerialize = obj => false;
            }
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

### C)

**Finally**, to serialize your model easily use the above `ContractResolver`. Set it up like this:

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Serializer settings
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // ContractResolver = new CustomResolver();
    // OR:
    ContractResolver = new CustomResolver(new []
    {
        nameof(PC.Libs), // keep Libs property among virtual properties
        nameof(PC.Files) // keep Files property among virtual properties
    }),
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// Do the serialization and output to the console
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new PC(), settings);
Console.WriteLine(json);

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
// We can see that "Books" filed is ignored in the output:
// {
//  "FileFolderId": 0,
//  "Libs": null,
//  "Files": null
// }
```

**Now**, all the navigation (relation) properties [`virtual` properties] will be ignored automatically except you keep some of them by determine them in your code.

### [Live DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jxF7LL)

---

Thanks from [@BrianRogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263/brian-rogers) for his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292010/how-do-i-make-json-net-ignore-object-relationships#21295181).

Comment: you are a life savior!!

Comment: This was an excellent answer. @RAM , would you know a way to conditionally include only specific virtual collections, may via custom annotation or some other way?

Comment: @Janne, I updated my answer to support keeping certain properties with their names (although we can make a solution based-on attributes too). Also I added a link to a Live Demo. 

Comment: Thanks for sharing @RAM, I will take this to consideration in future plans.

Comment: ... just a quick notice @RAM, code example here at StackOverflow is partial as it's missing handling of _namesOfVirtualPropsToKeep (just one more condition to IF-statement), but Live DEMO contains this missing feat. Just wanted to let you know. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @RAM , could you confirm something for me regarding this thread on virtual collections: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469432/entity-framework-code-first-lazy-loading ... When the models with virtual collections are fetched, but collections are never accessed anywhere before exposing 'em to custom resolver, are collection proxies ignored when using whitelisting? Basically I'd like to know if serializer *really completely ignores* virtual collections, so that EF won't try to fill 'em for nothing, as the serializer would ignore results anyway?

Comment: @Janne, I'm not sure about fetching the whitelisted virtual properties during serialization based on lazy loading. Really I turn off lazy loading in my projects. But you can use a EF profiles in a simple new application to test what will be happen exactly. [profiler1](https://stackify.com/entity-framework-profiler/), [profiler2](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using `Newtonsoft.Json`

Mark field with

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore
```

Instead of

```
System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore
```