# How to enforce usage of Newtonsoft.Json over System.Text.Json.Serialization

Tags: c#, json.net, resharper, using

I fell to the pitfall described in this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661593/1236401

Where some of my code was using `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json`, probably due to choosing wrong package when ReSharper suggested missing refernces:

[image: resharper]

Is there a way to disable suggestion of the specific attribute or namespace?

Is there a way to prevent referencing this namespace in general?

That is besides text search in the code files.

Comment: Add `using Newtonsoft.Json;` at the top of file?

Comment: Yes and what about new files..

Comment: I'm looking for a way to prevent other developers from making mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the following verification to the CI pipeline.

```sh
! grep --include=\*.cs -rnw . -e "System.Text.Json.Serialization"
```