# JsonIgnore is being ignored

Tags: c#, json, serialization, ignore

I am using the GeoJsonSerializer as I need to serialize several geomtetries.

```
 JsonSerializerSettings sett = new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }; // ignore Self referencing loop
 var serializer = GeoJsonSerializer.Create(sett);
 serializer.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; //pretty print
 using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(jsonFile))
 {
     serializer.Serialize(file, cities);
 }
```

and my class has this:

```
[JsonIgnore]
[NotMapped]
public string? OriginalSource { get; set; } = "UNK";

[XmlIgnore] // tempo
[JsonIgnore] // tempo
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Null")]
public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point? Location { get; set; }
```

Yet these fields still end up in my JSON output. Is there another attribute that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure you are applying [`[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonignoreattribute.htm) and not [`[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreAttribute]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute)?  Same class name, different namespace.  See e.g. [.NET Core 3 `[JsonIgnore]` not working when requesting single resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60661593).